# How to make a clean Join using different colums without duplicates

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have a table with all the students names and another table with student name and their enrollments in classes i want to show both students with their class names even if they are not enrolled in any classes i used union between the  enrolled and not enrolled the only problem that the names are duplicated

Student (student_id, student_name, major, level, age)
Enrolled (student_id, class_name, semester)

and here's the MySQL query:

select student_name,class_name from student natural join enrolled union select student_name,null as class_name from student group by student_name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT 
  s.student_name,
  e.class_name 
FROM 
  student s 
  LEFT JOIN enrolled e ON s.student_id = e.student_id 
GROUP BY student_name;
```

LEFT JOIN is used when one of the tables can have null values, whilst the other can not. The "left" table (student in this case) is the most important one, the "right" table (enrollment) is the one that can be null.

So it will ALWAYS find the student tables, but when it can't find a class_name that's linked to that student, it just shows up as NULL.

If you want multiple enrollments on the same student, you'll have to remove the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You should use LEFT JOIN like so: SELECT s.student_name, e.class_name from student s LEFT JOIN enrolled e ON s.student_id=e.student_id